# By showing less information am I letting the user focus on that information more?

Tags: mobile-application, lists, advertisement, choices

I'm developing an app which shows location based ads. If you are interested you swipe right, if not, you swipe left.

Initially, in my first prototype of the app I tried an infinite scroll, which turned out to look, in my opinion, very boring and easy to get distracted. Then, I thought about showing a fixed number of ads, I tried it and it turned out to be much easier to focus on those few ads.

By this logic, showing only one ad would be the best since the user can fully focus on that one, but since I'm showing ads, I also want the user to be able to find something they like without having to focus too much on every ad. Also I think that by showing more than one ad at the same time the user may feel they have more options.

My questions are:

- Is my premise right? (maybe an infinite scroll is my best choice)
- If showing a fixed number of ads at the same time is the best option, would one have the same impact on the user than showing three, or two?
- How would I show, for instance, three ads and make sure the user knows that he can be interested on all three, or none? (That he hasn't got to choose a single one)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Did you do any usability comparison testing **with actual users**? It's quite helpful AFAIK. Have you ever seen any website or app with the interface you propose? Infinite scroll (or sometimes pagination with long pages) is much more common (and better IMO) simply because it gives the users more flexibility.

Comment: I haven't seen any app with this exact interface, although it does follow most of Tinder's principles. Where would I get actual users to get my app tested? Thanks

Comment: You could try randomly assigning different users different possibilities and track their behavior. You should also allow feedback. As for other apps and websites, I was thinking of things such as search engines and social media.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends also on the target age and the population culture that you are targeting. In general I agree that the less you show the more someone will focus on that small amount of information, but depending on the context switch (if it happens a lot) or on fhe quality of words you use you could also confuse them a lot. I guess best is to try usability test and write down the evidences,l if you haven't tried yet :) Let me know, I am curiouse to see how it worked out for you!